# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds in .../ot-function.php on line 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm try to connect http://www.baustvisual.com and see that error. But admin menu working. Site working in wordpress. When i connect CPU working in 99-100% (that i saw in CPanel on hosting)

Comment: Check step by step code for that menu, which gives this error, or share some code related to that menu

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your code, if you place any error script that is taking too much time to load. Then after resolving that either place

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

at the top of your page or set `max_execution_time = 100` in php.ini file, where 100 is 100 seconds.